# How to wait until callback on appendFile work Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a method

```
private processWriteNextChunk(filePath: string): void {
    const nextChunk = this.data.get(filePath)?.shift();
    if (!nextChunk) return;
    appendFile(filePath, nextChunk.buffer, () => {
      nextChunk?.last ? this.data.delete(filePath) : this.emitWriteNextChunk(filePath);
    });
  }
```

And I'm testing it like

```
  it('should call appendFile when chunk array is not empty and delete data pair if it was last chunk',() => {
let appendFileCallback;
const appendFileSpy = jest.spyOn(fs, 'appendFile').mockImplementation((path, data, callback) => {
  appendFileCallback = callback;
});
const data: IBufferChunk = { ...MOCK_DATA, last: true };
service.data.set(MOCK_PATH, [data]);
service.processWriteNextChunk(MOCK_PATH);

expect(appendFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(MOCK_PATH, data.buffer, appendFileCallback);
expect(service.data.size).toBe(0);


});
```

test fails with

[image]

It happens because this.data.delete(filePath) doesn't have time to work, how I can fix this?

Comment: You should provide minimal, complete, reproduce example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `processWriteNextChunk` represent an async operation.

So if you mark the function as `async`, and return a promise

```
 private async processWriteNextChunk(filePath: string): Promise<YOUR_TYPE> { 
    //...
    return appendFile(...)
 }
```

Then, you can use `await` inside your jest `it`

```
it('should call appendFile when chunk array is not empty and call emitWriteNextChunk if it wasn\'t last chunk', async () => {
    //...
    await service.processWriteNextChunk(MOCK_PATH);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that mockImplementation function change the way how function works, so my callback haven't been called, so I just made it like

```
const appendFileSpy = jest
      .spyOn(fs, 'appendFile')
      .mockImplementation((path, data, callback) => {
        callback(null);
        appendFileCallback = callback;
      });
```

and it works fine